# No tool chain is available to build for platform 'armeabi-v7a'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

While running the sample NDK program [Native Audio](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/native-audio) in Android studio in Arch Linux I get the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileNative-audio-jniArmeabi-v7aDebugSharedLibraryNative-audio-jniMainC'.
>   No tool chain is available to build for platform 'armeabi-v7a':
>       - Tool chain 'ndk-clang' (Clang): Could not determine Clang version: failed to execute clang -dM -E -.

How can I correct this error? Do I need to make a tool chain so that i can run the sample ndk program?

Comment: I have the same issue. is it resolved ?

Comment: @ransh yup resolved. Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions:

1) download ndk-r12 from https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/wiki, scroll down to "current beta release", and point your android studio to use that version from native-audio/local.properties file

2) use your current ndk as-is, but comment out the following from native-audio/app/build.gradle
toolchain = 'clang'
then it will use gcc to build

Thanks to ggfan for [answering this question in github](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/issues/202#issuecomment-219350419)

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be in absence of some library required by **ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang**. Like:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Try to run it, check the error and install all the requirements.

For example, on Fedora it would be **sudo dnf install ncurses-compat-libs** for that particular library.